# How to set Custom Business Day End Frequency in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, calendar, offset, datetimeindex

I have a pandas dataframe with an unusual DatetimeIndex. The frame contains daily data (end of each day) from 1985 to 1990 but some "random" days are missing:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1985-01-02', '1985-01-03', '1985-01-04', '1985-01-07',
           '1985-01-08', '1985-01-09', '1985-01-10', '1985-01-11',
           '1985-01-14', '1985-01-15',
           ...
           '1990-12-17', '1990-12-18', '1990-12-19', '1990-12-20',
           '1990-12-21', '1990-12-24', '1990-12-26', '1990-12-27',
           '1990-12-28', '1990-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=1516, freq=None)
```

I often need operations like shifting an entire column such that a value that is at the last day of a month (which could e.g. in my DatetimeIndex be '1985-05-30') is shifted to the last day of the next (which could e.g. my DatetimeIndex be '1985-06-27').

While looking for a smart way to perform such shifts, I stumbled over *[Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)* provided by *[pandas.tseries.offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay)*. It can be observed that there are the aliases *custom business day frequency (C)* and *custom business month end frequency (CBM)*. When looking at an [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#custom-business-days), it seems like that this could provide exactly what I need:

```
mth_us = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
day_us = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
df['Col1_shifted'] = df['Col1'].shift(periods=1, freq = mth_us) # shifted by 1 month
df['Col2_shifted'] = df['Col2'].shift(periods=1, freq = day_us) # shifted by 1 day
```

The problem is that my DatetimeIndex is not equal to USFederalHolidayCalendar(). Can someone please tell me how I can use *pd.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd* (and also *pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay*) with my own custom DatetimeIndex?

If not, has any of you an idea how to tackle this issue in a different way?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: did you try the code with the US holidays? I mean when you shift the column to next monthend, it does though an error, no? as you have several values to assign to the same date